# Not sure what colors go to my new thermostat

Tags: thermostat

[image][image]Not sure what colors go where from my old one to my new one the old is on top and new is on bottom

Comment: Can you post photos of your furnace/air-handler, or its wiring diagram for that matter?

Comment: I figured it out I got in touch with Honeywell and they helped me out. Got it figured out and it’s working. Thanks though